# Mongodb - can't start mongodb on windows 10

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to start MongoDB on windows 10, by specifying the config file. The config file specifies the path to the database. When I run the mongodb daemon:

```
.\mongod.exe --config .\mongod.cfg
```

I get this error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-24T00:15:15.541Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":38,"codeName":"FileNotOpen","errmsg":"Failed to open C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.4\\log\\mongod.log"}}}
```

It complains that it can't access the log file. However I have verified that the log file exists in the location that it's complaining about:

```
 ls "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.4\\log\\mongod.log"


    Directory: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         1/23/2021   6:56 PM         100428 mongod.log
```

This is my mongod config:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

How can I get this party started?

Comment: It is rather uncommon to store logs and data under, `c:/Program Files/... `, better use folder like, `c:/Windows/Logs` or create dedicated folders for it.

Comment: Ok. That was the directory where the logs and data were when I installed mongo for the first time and started it up. I guess I can put them anywhere once I have more control over this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in "properties" of the log file, open "Security" and put permission to "write"

Comment: Thanks! Now it seems to start: `mongod --config mongod.cfg` but is not in fact running. :(
`mongosh
Current sessionID:  600cf0701ee7be98e19dd0c2
Connecting to:    mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

Comment: now you may need to unblock your firewall most probablt...

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't it. I tried turning my firewall completely off. And that didn't work. But then I tried starting it up with the `--dbath` flag, and noticed that it was complaining about not being able to access the `data` folder I had set. I gave my user full access to that folder and now it works just fine! At this point I should feel comfortable moving the logs and data anywhere I chose. Thanks for your help!